# Get post content from another section in custom single page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop

I created wp-theme, use plugin Custom Post Type UI.

Created sections - `Customers` and `Projects`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In page-projects.php, display list (links) all of customers:

[image]

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'customer'
   );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Im trying to display content from post `projects` (about customer).
Page `single-customer.php` display content from `customers`, but I need post from `projects`.

[image]

How get this post content? Its possible?

**UPD**

code in `single-customer.php`:

```
  `<div class="page-head text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="page-head_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>




<?php
// This is for projects posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        // loop here
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>`
```

**UPD**

if i use this code `<?php acf_form(); ?>` its display content which i need, but its display all textarea and inputs of wp-admin panel. if i use `<?php the_field('project-sections'); ?>` - its display `Array, Array, Array, Array`

Comment: @Marina , you want to add "projects" posts in single-customer.php ? it seems two custom post loop in the same page.

Comment: yes, i want to display post 'projects' in page 'single-customer.php'. how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution:

```
<?php if( have_rows('project-sections') ): ?>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>

        <?php while( have_rows('project-sections') ): the_row(); ?>

            <section class="<?php if ($i % 2 == 0) : ?>bg-gray<?php else: ?>bg-white<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="page-head_sub-title"><?php the_sub_field('project-sections-title'); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_sub_field('project-sections-description'); ?>
                </div>
            </section>

            <?php $i++; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Need to use

`<?php the_sub_field('name-sub-field'); ?>`

inside

`<?php while( have_rows('name-field') ): the_row(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple loops in the same page

```
<?php
// this is for customer posts
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'customer'
   );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
 <?php     // loop here
  the_title(); 
the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
 else : ?>
 <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    // This is for projects posts
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'projects'
   );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php     // loop here
  the_title(); 
the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
 else : ?>
 <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

You can also mix the posts like this

```
'post_type' => array('customer', 'projects'),
```

Comment: this code need to add in `single-customer.php` and `single-project.php` ?

Comment: You can add the codes in any page you like. To get the projects posts appear in single-customer.php, you don't have to create another single-project.php. ( Creating single-{custom}.php is only for single template. )

Comment: i add this code in `page-customer.php` - its display list of all customers, but dont get content post in project section. thank you for try to help, but i dont understand how use it

Comment: Make sure the custom post name is correct , "project" or "projects". To get the right answer, you will have to be more specific in your question. I suggest you to copy all your codes and ask here again.

Comment: i try "project" and "projects", not help. i update my question

Comment: I double checked the codes in my answer and it should work.
Instead of the screenshots, could you please update your question with the codes that you are trying to display? I mean the codes that are in single-customer.php. I guess something might be wrong in your codes.

Comment: sorry, your code works, its display title. but not display content

Comment: i added code in single-customer.php

Comment: ok I got it, you can print the content like this <?php the_content(); ?> 

check out here if you want to print the other stuffs such as categories, tags, date.. etc.
https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

Comment: I updated my answer with **the_content();**

Comment: your code display only titles of customers on the same page. if i use this code `<?php acf_form(); ?>` its display content which i need, but its display all textarea and inputs of wp-admin panel. if i use `<?php the_field('project-sections'); ?>` - its display `Array, Array, Array, Array`